# New Facebook in-app sounds

Tags: ios, audio, facebook

In the last update, the Facebook app for iOS 8 has started adding squishing/swooshing nosies as you navigate or like posts. How do you disable these annoying noises? I have notifications set to off, sounds set to off for the app, but short of muting my entire phone, they keep existing. I don't want to have to mute everything, just the in-app noises for FB.

Answer (score 1):

In the app, go to tab More. Then Settings → Sound and disable In-App Sound.